# Firefox 49.0 doesn't show words in italics on Wikipedia

Tags: release-loki, display, firefox

I have encountered a weird problem with the recent version of Mozilla Firefox (49.0) on Loki. There seems to be a bug when displaying Wikipedia pages - words in italics are simply left out. See e.g. here:

[image]

With Google Chrome 53.0.2785.143

[image]

and Chromium 53.0.2785.143

[image]

there's no problem at all. I haven't noticed the issue on any other web page except Wikipedia.

Any ideas?!?

Comment: Weird - I pulled up the same page on my copy of Firefox 49 and the italics displayed fine. Are other websites affected? Have you installed any extra font packages or the like?

Comment: Not that I would have noticed. I can't remember installing extra font packages either

Answer (score 1):

[image: Firefox]

I'm unable to reproduce the error. I suggest right-clicking on the area you want to inspect and selecting "Inspect Element". Look if anything is out of the ordinary or try to toggle the CSS if you don't have the italics element showing like I do above. Page might just need a refresh.

Worst comes to worst, reinstall Firefox. It's likely something off with your configuration. If the issue recurs, it's a bug to take to Firefox's bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks wolf. I've purged and reinstalled Firefox, the problem persists. I couldn't tell by inspecting the element that anything was unusual. I'll file a bug report I guess

Comment: @deesnook, what about add-ons? Have you tried removing Firefox's extensions? Not sure what that blue "S" in the upper-right corner is

Comment: the only add-on I have is NoScript (the blue S). Uninstalling didn't help :(

Comment: What did you have loaded in NoScript and did you try turning off those effects before uninstalling it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're driving at. I used NoScript with the default settings blocking scripts, but whitelisting some websites I commonly use (including Wikipedia of course). Also after purging Firefox it didn't work either, even without NoScript

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall extensions and [reset firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems). If the problem persists, try to reinstall it

Comment: the only add-on I have is NoScript. Uninstalling didn't help :( reinstall either

Answer (score 0):

Same symptoms here, running Ubuntu.  Turns out the italic version of the font was not installed properly.

In Ubuntu, reinstalling the package `fonts-freefont-ttf` fixed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-freefont-ttf
```